# How to hide the pointer in bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Folks I am using the bootstarp-datepicker plugin.

I am wondering how I can turn off the pointer that shows up when you open the date picker ? [image]

Comment: Inspect the markup with developer tools in the browser to find out what element/CSS selector is responsible for it. Then hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CSS to hide it:

```
.datepicker:before, .datepicker:after {
    content: none;
}
```